# Add field for an each element in .json file

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have this code

````
const Command = require("../Structures/Command.js");
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { menu } = require("../data/menu.json");
let x = 0;
let menuEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("#FFA500")
    .setTitle("Menu")
    .setDescription("Here are the cool things you can order with an \"order\" command")
    for(x < menu; x++;){
        menuEmbed.addField( menu[x].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + menu[x].slice(1).replace("_", " "), "```id:" + menu[x] + "```" );
    }

module.exports = new Command({
    name: "menu",
    description: "Gives you a menu",

    async run(message, args, client){
        message.reply(menuEmbed);
    }
});
````

What I want it to do is to add a field for each thing in the menu.json. Is it even possible?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you show us an example of your `menu.json` to give you a more accurate answer.

Comment: "menu":  ["coffee", "donut", "tea"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `menu` is just defined as an Array (as I suspect by your comment) then just changing the code for the for-loop should suffice:

````js
for (var entry in menu){
  menuEmbed.addField(menu[entry].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + menu[entry].slice(1).replace("_", " "), "```id:" + menu[entry] + "```" )
}
````

Or you could use a simple forEach loop and ditch he iterator:

````js
menu.forEach(food => {
    menuEmbed.addField(food.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + food.slice(1).replace("_", " "), "```id:" + food + "```" )
})
````

> Note: `Array.forEach` is said to be slower

Also: keep in mind, that there is a limited number of fields an Embed can have